# What is the best way to avoid I/O operation on main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Is it possible to move I/O operation to the outside main thread, and return the result to main thread?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But that's not what you actually wanted to hear, right? Please, specify your question.

Comment: Ultimately you need to post that work on Worker thread .. Options can be `RXJava`, `AsyncTask` , `Thread` , `Executers` and `Coroutines` etc ..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using a static variable.

Another possibility is `ExecutorService`. It has a Method `submit(Callable)`, you can start the Thread with it and it returns a `Future` object. You can use this to get the returned Object.
`Calleble<>` is something like `Runnable`, but it can Return something.